# Surface Integral of Scalar Field: Wiki definition question

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

[Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_integral) defines the surface integral of a scalar field as:

$$
\iint_S f \,\mathrm dS
= \iint_T f(\mathbf{r}(s, t)) \left\|{\partial \mathbf{r} \over \partial s} \times {\partial \mathbf{r} \over \partial t}\right\| \mathrm ds\, \mathrm dt
$$

where $f : \mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R$ and $\mathbf r$ is later defined $\mathbf r : \mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R^3$ and $\mathbf r(s,t) = (s, t, f(s,t))$

**Question** is Wiki correct?  It seems $f$ is used with both 2 and 3 arguments.

I think above should be defined:
$$
\iint_S f \,\mathrm dS
= \iint_T f(s, t) \left\|{\partial \mathbf{r} \over \partial s} \times {\partial \mathbf{r} \over \partial t}\right\| \mathrm ds\, \mathrm dt
$$